# Need help optimizing my Javascript for canvas rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, canvas

I've written this quick script for random moving lines for the background for my portfolio. It works smoothly alone but when I start working with other CSS animations and stuff, there's a frame drop at the beginning (later it runs smooth). At least on my PC, struggles on low-end PC.

Some tips to optimize it would be helpful.

Here's my code:

```js
/*Random Line Render Script aka Mini Browser Crasher */
/*XD Can't Revise This Script. Rofl Drains Memory. May crash low-end pc :V */
var c = document.getElementById("graph");
var dimension = [document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientHeight];
c.width = dimension[0];

var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = c.getContext("2d");
var posx = [100, 200, 150, 100, 0];
var posy = [100, 200, 300, 100, -100];
var posx2 = [600, 400, 200, 600];
var posy2 = [500, 200, 100, 150, 500, 500];
var posx3 = [];
var posy3 = [];

/*Generate random values for array( random starting point ) */
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  posx2.push(500 + Math.round(Math.random() * 700));
  posy2.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 900));
}
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  posx3.push(1000 + Math.round(Math.random() * 300));
  posy3.push(0 + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000));
}
var posx_len = posx.length;
var posx2_len = posx2.length;
var posx3_len = posx3.length;
var xa, ya;
var opa = 1;
var amount = 0.01;
var sinang = 0;
var distance1 = 0;
var distance2 = 0;
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', (function(event) {
  xa = event.clientX;
  ya = event.clientY;
}));

/*Render Lines */
function draw() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 10000, 10000);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(posx[0], posy[0]);
  for (var i = 0; i < posx_len; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(posx[i], posy[i]);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,' + opa + ')';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.arc(posx[i], posy[i], 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  }

  if (opa > 1) {
    amount = -0.01 * Math.random();
  }
  if (opa < 0) {
    amount = 0.01 * Math.random();
  }
  opa = opa + amount;

  ctx.moveTo(posx2[0], posy2[0]);
  for (var i = 0; i < posx2_len; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(posx2[i], posy2[i]);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,' + opa + ')';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.arc(posx2[i], posy2[i], 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  }
  ctx.moveTo(posx3[0], posy3[0]);
  for (var i = 0; i < posx3_len; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(posx3[i], posy3[i]);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,' + opa + ')';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.arc(posx3[i], posy3[i], 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  }
  sinang = sinang + 0.01;

  /*Frame Render Ends here*/

  /*Calculation for next frame*/
  for (var i = 0; i < posx_len; i++) {
    posx[i] = posx[i] + (Math.cos(sinang) * i) / 2; /* Sin curve for smooth value transition. Smooth assss Butter */
    posy[i] = posy[i] + (Math.cos(sinang) * i) / 2;
    /* Can't believe Distance Formula is useful ahaha  */

    distance1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((posx[i] - xa), 2) + Math.pow((posy[i] - ya), 2));

    if (distance1 <= 500) {
      ctx.moveTo(posx[i], posy[i]);
      ctx.lineTo(xa, ya);
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < posx2_len; j++) {
      distance12 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((posx[i] - posx2[j]), 2) + Math.pow((posy[i] - posy2[j]), 2));

      if (distance12 <= 500) {
        ctx.moveTo(posx[i], posy[i]);
        ctx.lineTo(posx2[j], posy2[j]);
      }
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < posx3_len; j++) {
      distance13 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((posx[i] - posx3[j]), 2) + Math.pow((posy[i] - posy3[j]), 2));

      if (distance13 <= 500) {
        ctx.moveTo(posx[i], posy[i]);
        ctx.lineTo(posx3[j], posy3[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  posx[posx.length - 1] = posx[0];
  posy[posy.length - 1] = posy[0];

  /*Repeat Above Steps. Should have done this in Multi-dimensional array. Ugh I feel sad now*/
  for (var i = 0; i < posx2_len; i++) {
    posx2[i] = posx2[i] + (Math.sin(sinang) * i) / 2;
    posy2[i] = posy2[i] - (Math.sin(sinang) * i) / 2;

    distance2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((posx2[i] - xa), 2) + Math.pow((posy2[i] - ya), 2));

    if (distance2 <= 500) {
      ctx.moveTo(posx2[i], posy2[i]);
      ctx.lineTo(xa, ya);
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < posx3_len; j++) {
      distance22 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((posx2[i] - posx3[j]), 2) + Math.pow((posy2[i] - posy3[j]), 2));

      if (distance22 <= 500) {
        ctx.moveTo(posx2[i], posy2[i]);
        ctx.lineTo(posx3[j], posy3[j]);
      }
    }
  }

  posx2[posx2.length - 1] = posx2[0];
  posy2[posy2.length - 1] = posy2[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < posx3_len; i++) {
    posx3[i] = posx3[i] - (Math.sin(sinang) * i) / 1.2;
    posy3[i] = posy3[i] - (Math.sin(sinang) * i) / 1.2;

    distance2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((posx3[i] - xa), 2) + Math.pow((posy3[i] - ya), 2));
    if (distance2 <= 500) {
      ctx.moveTo(posx3[i], posy3[i]);
      ctx.lineTo(xa, ya);
    }
  }
  posx3[posx3.length - 1] = posx3[0];
  posy3[posy3.length - 1] = posy3[0];

  ctx.restore();
  ctx.stroke();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
body {
  background: #1f1f1f;
}
```

```html
<canvas height="1080px" width="1100px" id="graph">
</canvas>
```

Comment: This code is stroking many times the same sub-paths for nothing, it sets strokeStyle without ever using it, it clears a crazy big area for nothing, it tries to restore states that were never saved. It's quite unclear how all these issues should be fixed because the intentions of each block of code are not self-explanatory, but at a glance I'd say remove all the calls to `ctx.stroke()` except the last one, you should win a few ms per frame.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. It's actually my first time working with canvas so I had no idea that I had to stroke just once per frame. I thought we were supposed to stroke every time we drew a line/polygon. Couldn't squeeze out much ms but yea thanks. :V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I've done is used square colliders instead of circular(distance formula) and it has faster runtime now. (not much but still)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
    body{
        background: #1f1f1f;
    }
    canvas{

    }
</style>
<body >
    <canvas height="1080px" width="1100px" id="graph">
        
    </canvas>
</body>

<script>
/*Random Line Render Script aka Mini Browser Crasher */
/*XD Can't Revise This Script. Rofl Drains Memory. May crash low-end pc :V */
var c = document.getElementById("graph");
var dimension = [document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientHeight];
c.width = dimension[0];

var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 
var posx = [100,200,150,100,0];
var posy = [100,200,300,100,-100];
var posx2 = [600,400,200,600];
var posy2 = [500,200,100,150,500,500];
var posx3 = [];
var posy3 = [];

/*Generate random values for array( random starting point ) */
for(var i=0; i<2;i++){
    posx2.push(500+Math.round(Math.random()*700));
    posy2.push(Math.round(Math.random()*900));
}
for(var i=0; i<5;i++){
    posx3.push(1000+Math.round(Math.random()*300));
    posy3.push(0+Math.round(Math.random()*1000));
}
var posx_len = posx.length;
var posx2_len = posx2.length;
var posx3_len = posx3.length;
var xa,ya;
var opa =1;
var amount = 0.01;
var sinang = 0;
var distance1 = 0;
var distance2 = 0;
var t1, t2;
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', (function (event) {
    xa = event.clientX;
    ya = event.clientY;
    

}));

/*Render Lines */
function draw(){
    
    t1 =performance.now();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1920,1080);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(posx[0], posy[0]);
    for(var i= 0; i<posx_len;i++){
        ctx.lineTo(posx[i], posy[i]);
        
        ctx.arc(posx[i],posy[i], 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

    }
    
    
    if(opa>1){
    amount = -0.01*Math.random();
    }
    if(opa<0){
        amount =0.01*Math.random();
    }
    opa =opa +amount;
    
    ctx.moveTo(posx2[0], posy2[0]);
    for(var i = 0; i<posx2_len;i++){
        ctx.lineTo(posx2[i], posy2[i]);
        
        ctx.arc(posx2[i],posy2[i], 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    }
    ctx.moveTo(posx3[0], posy3[0]);
    for(var i = 0; i<posx3_len;i++){
        ctx.lineTo(posx3[i], posy3[i]);
        
        ctx.arc(posx3[i],posy3[i], 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    }
    sinang = sinang+0.01;
    
    /*Frame Render Ends here*/

    /*Calculation for next frame*/
    for(var i = 0;i<posx_len;i++){
        posx[i] = posx[i]+ (Math.cos(sinang)*i)/2;/* Sin curve for smooth value transition. Smooth assss Butter */
        posy[i] = posy[i]+ (Math.cos(sinang)*i)/2;
        /* Can't believe Distance Formula is useful ahaha  */
    
        

    
        if(Math.abs(posx[i]-xa)<500 && Math.abs(posy[i]-ya)<500){
            ctx.moveTo(posx[i],posy[i]);
            ctx.lineTo(xa, ya);
        }
        
        for(var j = 0;j<posx2_len;j++){
            
            
            if(Math.abs(posx[i]-posx2[j])<500 && Math.abs(posy[i]-posy2[j])<500){
                ctx.moveTo(posx[i],posy[i]);
                ctx.lineTo(posx2[j], posy2[j]);
            }
        }
        for(var j = 0;j<posx3_len;j++){
            
            
            if(Math.abs(posx[i]-posx3[j])<500 && Math.abs(posy[i]-posy3[j])<500){
                ctx.moveTo(posx[i],posy[i]);
                ctx.lineTo(posx3[j], posy3[j]);
            }
        }

    }
    posx[posx.length-1]=posx[0];
    posy[posy.length-1] = posy[0];

    /*Repeat Above Steps. Should have done this in Multi-dimensional array. Ugh I feel sad now*/
    for(var i = 0;i<posx2_len;i++){
    
        posx2[i] = posx2[i]+ (Math.sin(sinang)*i)/2;
        posy2[i] = posy2[i]-(Math.sin(sinang)*i)/2;
        
        
        
        if(Math.abs(posx2[i]-xa)<500 && Math.abs(posy2[i]-ya)<500){
            ctx.moveTo(posx2[i],posy2[i]);
            ctx.lineTo(xa, ya);
        }
    
        
        for(var j = 0;j<posx3_len;j++){
            
            
            if(Math.abs(posx2[i]-posx3[j])<500 && Math.abs(posy2[i]-posy3[j])<500){
                ctx.moveTo(posx2[i],posy2[i]);
                ctx.lineTo(posx3[j], posy3[j]);
            }
        }
        
        
    }

    posx2[posx2.length-1]=posx2[0];
    posy2[posy2.length-1] = posy2[0];
    
    for(var i = 0;i<posx3_len;i++){
    
        posx3[i] = posx3[i]- (Math.sin(sinang)*i)/1.2;
        posy3[i] = posy3[i]-(Math.sin(sinang)*i)/1.2;
        
        
        if(Math.abs(posx3[i]-xa)<500 && Math.abs(posy3[i]-ya)<500){
            ctx.moveTo(posx3[i],posy3[i]);
            ctx.lineTo(xa, ya);
        }
        

        
        
        
    }
    posx3[posx3.length-1]=posx3[0];
    posy3[posy3.length-1] = posy3[0];
    

    ctx.restore();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,'+opa+')';
    ctx.stroke();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    t2=performance.now();
    console.log(t2-t1);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Store answers of calculations in temporary variables (I know C++ usually is smart enough to catch those mistakes, but javascript... I wouldn't trust it). It's not smart to calculate `(Math.cos(sinang)*i)/2` multiple times. Nor is it smart to calculate `(Math.sin(sinang)*i)/1.2` multiple times. Or `posx3.length-1`. Start factorizing your calculations so you only do them once and then reuse the answer multiple times. - Try to keep your comments professional and less "*Ugh I feel sad now*". - Good job with indentation. Split up HTML and JS next time so the code has nice colors for both languages.